# For loop in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

greetings all
I want to insert 70 records in a table
the values are value1,value2,...value70
and I was wondering if it's possible to accomplish this through a SQL query
I am using postgresql db.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where do the values come from?  Are they arbtrary values?  Just use a multiple insert statement, like:

```
INSERT INTO t (colname) VALUES ('value1'), ('value2'), ..., ('value70');
```

Are they values that can be generated from the integers 1 to 70?  If so, use the set returning function `generate_series`:

```
INSERT INTO t (colname) SELECT 'value'||i FROM generate_series(1,70) AS s(i);
```

Are they just in some other table?  Just reference it normally:

```
INSERT INTO t (colname) SELECT val FROM othert;
```

Comment: the values are generated from 1-70, and what about if i want to insert in the record other values in other columns, how would the syntax be like ?

Comment: You simply add the columns and the values (as expressions in terms of i) to the column lists.  For example if you wanted to insert (1,1), (2,4), (3,9), etc., you would simply do "INSERT INTO t(n, nsqr) SELECT i, i*i FROM generate_series AS s(i)".

Comment: thanks for the feedback a lot, but i want the second value to be something fixed like "testing", how would that be.

Comment: Easy, just use "... SELECT i, 'testing' FROM generate_series ...".